# Help regarding a proposition in Royden(4th ed)

Tags: measure-theory

Let $(X,M,\mu)$ be a measure space and $\phi$ a non-negative simple function.

Given $X_0\subset X$, $X_0\in M$ and $\mu(X\setminus X_0)=0$, how do I show that $$ \int_{X_0} \phi~d\mu = \int_X \phi~d\mu.$$

Comment: What theorems do you know about integrals?

Comment: well, I was first asked to show that if $A$ and $B$ are disjoint then $\int_{A\cup B} \phi~ d\mu = \int_A \phi ~d\mu + \int_B \phi~d\mu$ which I was able to show. then, the proposition went further and said that in particular...(the body of my post), but I fail to see the connection.

Comment: What about, $\int_{X_0\cup (X\setminus X_0)}\phi d\mu=\int_X \phi d\mu$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the formula $\displaystyle\int_{A\cup B} \phi~ d\mu = \int_A \phi ~d\mu + \int_B \phi~d\mu$ you have derived with $A=X_0$ and $B=X\setminus X_0$, we have
$$\int_{X} \phi~ d\mu = \int_{X_0} \phi ~d\mu + \int_{X\setminus X_0} \phi~d\mu.$$
If we can prove that $\displaystyle\int_{X\setminus X_0} \phi~d\mu=0$, then we are done.

To prove this, note that $\phi$ is a nonnegative simple function, we have $\phi=\sum_{i=1}^na_i\textbf{1}_{A_i}$ for some measurable sets $A_i$ and $a_i\geq 0$. Then 
$$0\leq\int_{X\setminus X_0} \phi~d\mu=\sum_{i=1}^na_i\int_{X\setminus X_0} \textbf{1}_{A_i}~d\mu=\sum_{i=1}^na_i\mu(A_i\cap(X\setminus X_0)).$$
By assumption $\mu(X\setminus X_0)=0$, we have $\mu(A_i\cap(X\setminus X_0))\leq \mu(X\setminus X_0)=0$, which implies that last term in the above equality is zero. This proves that $\displaystyle\int_{X\setminus X_0} \phi~d\mu=0$.

Comment: @Bill: You are welcome.